# Image position on view iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have some problem with image dragging. So I use this code:

```
-(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = player1.center;
    imageViewPosition.x +=translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y +=translation.y;
    player1.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    [self SaveColorRealTime];
}

-(void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer {
    CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
    player1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(player1.transform, scale, scale);
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;

}

-(void)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer {
    CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation;
    player1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(player1.transform, angle);
    rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;
}

-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        player1.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
        player1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



player1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [player1 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer]; 

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
[player1 addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationDetected:)];
[player1 addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[player1 addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

It works, user can drag image on view, but when user go to other view, position of image is refresh. 
Have you any ideas how can I save image position?
Thanks

Comment: just write your viewDidLoad code in viewWillAppear and check

Comment: thanks! but it still not working

Comment: what's it telling ? i mean crashing or not loading ?

Comment: Nothing! it is no difference between using viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. I mean it works the same.

Comment: Add your code to ViewDidAppear then ..... try it and let me know :)

Comment: I have already done it. But the result is the same)